# Автоматическое форматирование кода в Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Привет! Знаю, что вопрос вообще не к вам, но в гугле пока что не получается найти. Как в упомянутой в заголовке ide сделать так, чтобы она автоматически форматировала код, который я ввожу, руководствуясь настройками code style
То есть, я ввожу

```
if(a<b){
```

Нажимаю куда-нибудь, а ещё лучше автоматически, и это переписывается в виде

```
if (a < b) {
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> - Reformat code

[`IntelliJ IDEA Default Keymap.pdf`](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf)

Comment: Да, спасибо.

Comment: Из соседнего ответа: «В некоторых системах сочетание клавиш 'Ctrl + Alt + L' вызовет совсем не ту реакцию, которую вы ожидали. В Linux Ubuntu такое сочетание вызовет блокировку сессии пользователя.»

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> - Reformat code (Linux)
<kbd>Win</kbd> - кнопка значка 'Windows'
Для Mac это сочетание клавиш: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

Объяснение: В некоторых системах и виртуальных машинах сочетание клавиш <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> вызовет совсем не ту реакцию, которую вы ожидали. В Linux Ubuntu такое сочетание вызовет блокировку сессии пользователя. Блокировку экрана.
[Официальная документация по Idea](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-code-editor.html)

PS. В Idea вы можете изменить сочетание клавиш по умолчанию. Это может понадобится, если они конфликтуют с сочетаниями клавиш вашей системы.

Answer (score 2):

**Автоматически переформатировать код при сохранении**﻿

Вы можете настроить IDE для автоматического переформатирования кода в измененных файлах при сохранении изменений .

Нажмите **Ctrl+Alt+S**, чтобы открыть настройки IDE, и выберите **Tools | Actions on Save**.

Включите параметр **Reformat code**.

Кроме того, вы можете настроить способ, которым IDE будет переформатировать ваш код:

Щелкните **Configure scope** , чтобы указать шаблоны имен файлов и каталогов, которые вы хотите исключить из переформатирования .

В списке **All file types** выберите типы файлов, в которых вы хотите переформатировать код.

Выберите **Whole file** or **Changed lines**, если ваш проект находится под контролем версий.

Если выбрать **Changed lines** , переформатирование будет применяться только к тем строкам кода, которые были изменены локально, но еще не возвращены в репозиторий.

**Automatically reformat code on save**﻿

You can configure the IDE to reformat code in modified files automatically when your changes are saved.

Press Ctrl+Alt+S to open the IDE settings and select **Tools | Actions on Save**.

Enable the **Reformat code** option.

Additionally, you can configure the way the IDE will reformat your code:

Click **Configure scope** to specify the patterns of filenames and directories that you want to exclude from reformatting.

From the **All file types** list, select the types of files in which you want to reformat code.

Select **Whole file** or **Changed lines** if your project is under version control.

If you select **Changed lines**, reformatting will apply only to the lines of code that have been changed locally, but not yet checked in to the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Дополню: в некоторых случаях может быть и `Alt`+`Shift`+`L` (по умолчанию).

[image: Reformat code]